# Synchronous Blocking Animation Slider Function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, animation, nonblocking

Possibly this has been discussed a zillion times and I'm over thinking this, but...

How does one create a 'blocking' jQuery animation?

I have a page which has a 'special' slider animation that executes the first time a user visits the site. But there is a 'normal' slider animation that fires every time the user visits the same page. Since both animations fire with document.ready() they both occur at the same time. What I -want- is for the first animation to fire and then when the user clicks a button to close the window -then- the second animation fires.

```
//pseudocode

jQuery( init );
    function init() {
      if(firstVisit) {
        Animation1();  //Special. Only shows 1st visit to site
        Animation2(); 
      } else {
        Animation2(); 
      }
    }
}();
```

Here's the site: http://jchmusic.com

I guess I can re-write the code for -both- so that the second one explicitly starts only when the user clicks the 'close' button on the first animation, but to -me- it would look much cleaner if I could just make the code on the first animation 'blocking'... ie. the second animation doesn't start until the first animation returns. I messed about with SetTimeOut and various 'loops' and all it does is hang the browser... I'm sure this has been mulled over many times.

Any ideas?

Comment: "blocking" has a different meaning in JavaScript, which is liable to lead to confusion. It typically means that script execution (and UI responsiveness) stops until a particular bit of code executes.

Comment: Ah... thanks for the clarification. Is 'synchronous' or 'serialized' more appropriate?

Comment: *Queueing* is what you're looking for. You want animations that are queued to execute one after the other. This is done via callbacks, but I don't have time to give you a better answer at the moment.

Comment: I thought queues were for -elements-. Perhaps I should not have used the term 'animation' either as what I am doing involves SetInterval() and several elements. How do I 'queue' them all in one go and then make all the elements in the next 'animation' what in that same queue before it can execute? The examples I've seen all are based on a single element. TIA ---JC